# Unable to get my external monitor working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, hdmi, switchable-graphics

After the latest update Ubuntu 20.04 is unable to detect my monitor. My graphics card is Nvidia RTX 2060.

[image: available drivers screenshot]

I have tried all the drivers in the list of drivers in Additional Drivers, but I had no luck. It still isn't detected.

Comment: Maybe because your computer are using the integrated Intel GPU and the HDMI is connected to GPU RTX 2060. Check this tutorial switching GPU on Nvidia X Server may can help you.
https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu/amp

Comment: i have tried this switching as well but didnt work, it was working fine but stopped after updates, and now can downgrade to older versions